# How can I find the bound an integral if I know the value of that integral?

Tags: statistics, improper-integrals

I am trying to make an inverse Student's t-distribution function for my TI-83+ calculator, and I am caught on finding the actual value (a t-score) from the function and the probability (integral of the function) I want to find the "b" in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXXS0.png) picture.

More generally, I would like to be able to solve for the upper limit of an integral given that I know the value and the lower limit of the function.

I want the "$\Bbb b$" in this expression: $\int_{-\infty}^\Bbb b f(x,d) dx$ where $f(x,d)$ is, in my case, the t-distribution function $f(x,d)={(\frac {d+1}2-1)!\over (\frac d2-1)!\sqrt {d\pi}}*(1+\frac {x^2}d)^{-\frac {d+1}2}$ where d is a constant (the degrees of freedom)

For my TI function, I have downloaded a Gamma function for the factorials and am hoping the built-in fnInt( function works okay with what I need it to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the ability to compute the upper limit of the one-sided confidence interval with the corresponding area.

With this idea, [here](http://www.professortrimble.com/uploads/2/7/6/4/27642789/how_to_program_invt_into_ti-83.pdf) is a document teaching us how to compute the inverse of t-distribution for TI-83.

```
PROGRAM: INVT
:Input "AREA LEFT: ", A
:Input "DF: ", D
:1->S
:If A<.5
:Then
:-1 -> S
:End
:abs(2*A-1)->A
:TInterval 0, sqrt(D+1), (D+1), A
:Disp upper*S
:
```

Comment: OHHH so am I correct in thinking that the integral of a PDF, or my initial f(x,d), is just the CDF?

Comment: integrating pdf up to point $x$ give you the CDF value at $x$.